# Maven dependencies exclusions not working

Tags: java, maven, maven-enforcer-plugin

I'm using `enforcer` plugin of Maven and I see a behavior that I dont quite understand and it's dangerous.

Let's say that I have a conflict since dependency `A` has `bla.jar:1.0` and is in conflict with my dependnecy `B` which has `bla.jar:2.0`

Then to fix the conflict, I make an exclude of `bla.jar:1.0` from `A`

```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>com.foo</groupId>
      <artifactId>A</artifactId>
      <version>a.version.bla</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>com.omg</groupId>
          <artifactId>bla</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
   </dependency>
```

expecting the application will get the `bla.jar:2.0` fron classpath. But then I see when I run some unit test that the java proce3ss cannot find `bla.jar` ion the classpath at all and is giving me `ClassNotFound` in runtime.

Any idea what's wrong here?

I have in my pom defined from top to bottom B and then A

Comment: Please post the full pom file...

Comment: I´m afraid I cannot it contains libraries with company information that I cannot show

Comment: Make sure no other dependency is importing `com.omg.bla` library.

Comment: So, compile-time is fine but runtime is not? How is it ensured that your runtime artifact contains `bla.jar`?

Comment: Actually is from B where I was expected to have bla.jar but after the exclude from A, is not in the classpath anymore

Comment: compile time it cannot fail since is bla.jar is a dependency that is using internally by B, but since I exclude from A, is not in the classpath anymore, and when dependency B try to use it it fail

Comment: Perhaps `B` has set the dependency to e. g. "provided"?

Comment: I´m afraid not, and that's why I´m so confuse and I dont understand :(

Comment: In situations like this I usually advise to reduce complexity - create a new project with only dependency to `B`, build and check if it works. If yes, add the dependency to `A`, build and check if it still works or if there are conflicts etc.

Answer (score 4):

Please note that exclusions are *not* the best way to resolve dependency version conflicts.

The best approach is to use `<dependencyManagement>`. It allows you to set a version that replaces all transitive versions of that dependency.

In your case, I would first change the exclusion to `<dependencyManagement>`. Then I would proceed in the following way:

1. Check `mvn dependency:list` which version of the dependency is on the classpath. It should be the one specified in `<dependencyManagement>` unless there is no version of that dependency in your dependency tree. If you find more than one, then probably the groupId changed at some point. Then you need exclusions.
2. Check the scope of the dependency and verify that it is indeed `compile`.
3. Then open the dependency jar and see whether this jar really contains the class for which you get `ClassNotFound`. Often classes change from version to version.